# Fadeout label after an ASP button click jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, label

I have an asp.net button and label. How can I fire a label fadeout when this button is clicked. I am trying to use jquery to do this but it does not work. Here is my code. Any feedback helps. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btn_submit").click(function () {

        $('#lb_msg').fadeOut(8000, function () {

        });

    });

});


<asp:button id="btn_submit" text="click" runat="server"/>
<asp:label id="lb_msg" runat="server"/>
```

--- Here is the generated html script

```
<form method="post" action="test.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/CSZ/HAfM7368Pgeq6mI3czHpU3XISmFKiVp7wr7W6AwrjALoUT7cHc4Mn9x3H7F0LrLoWNdloyuwNBeMxIYMnooWzJvmyaIUlnHa15MOVo=" />
</div>
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="75BBA7D6" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="qTZ1IHxPMMoDPPo8HExyPgB9YNapexdmtB8/3VSBM+6DDolj7t7VSBMhzXfsJDWsyffjWQYo7kFl8Zm+ZBMPXNEk4uWdk5hRY14+ubqTvjd+IB8OtoRjyPCcu2fAWq7u" />
</div>
<div>

<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="click" id="btn_submit" />
<span id="lb_msg">fade me out</span>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btn_submit").click(function () {
    $('#' + 'lb_msg').fadeOut(8000, function () {

    });

});

});


</script>
```

Comment: you need to do `$('#' + '<%= lb_msg.ClientID %>').fadeOut` since it will create a different id in the source if it is running at server. same goes for the button submit

Comment: It still not working after replacing $('#' + '<%= lb_msg.ClientID %>').fadeOut

Comment: can you share your generated html?

Comment: Please see above for generated html

Comment: you `button` is of type `submit` so when you click it, its going to cause a `postback` and you will not be able to see the `fadeOut` effect. see this http://jsfiddle.net/1kmwys57/

Comment: How to get this work with postback?

Comment: you can try `$("#btn_submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#lbl_msg').fadeOut("8000", function(){
        //Once button has faded, invoke the form submission
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});`

Comment: Yes that does it. Thank you so much.

Comment: great. let me post it as an answer. please accept and upvote it as an answer @user3690095

Comment: I've posted my answer @user3690095. please upvote and accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep your form `submit` and the `fadeOut` event together what you can do is use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting and then you can do your `fadeOut` animation and on complete call the form.submit.

try this

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#lbl_msg').fadeOut("8000", function() { //Once button has faded, invoke the form submission 
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.